# Using swipe gesture to edit table view cells in swift3

Tags: swift3, uitableview, swipe-gesture

How can I use Swip gesture to do "edit" and "delete" action on Each table view cell? Something like the email app! Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> Bool {
  // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
  return true
}
// Override to support editing the table view.

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle 
   editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
   }
  else if editingStyle == .insert {
      // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it 
         into the array, and add a new row to the table view
   }

}
```